# Regex patterns in find module (Ansible)

Tags: regex, ansible, find

I am trying to get a return of directory names in a server. I only want those directories with 3 (and only 3) characters.

I even tried to use the 'exclude' parameter ( excludes: '\S{4,}' ), to make sure it would work. It didn't.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
  - find:
      paths: /workdir
      file_type: directory
      use_regex: yes
      patterns: '\S{3}'
    register: oea

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.path }}"
    with_items: "{{ oea.files }}"
```

I expect all directories with 3 and only 3 characters, but the actual output is every directory under /workdir.

Am I using the regex pattern the wrong way?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm looking for directories only

Comment: @gr0gu3 in that case you need to add `$` too which means end of line, so it will be `/^\S{3}$/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this task seems to be working for me:

```
  - find:
      paths: /tmp
      file_type: directory
      use_regex: yes
      patterns: '^\S{3}$'
    register: oea
```

i.e, add the `^` and `$` to define the start/end of the string you are searching for.

by the way, this matches directories with 3 "symbols" only (for example, a.c will be a match), if you want to narrow it to match only latin characters (directory name: abc) you should use like:

```
patterns: '^[a-zA-Z]{3}$'
```

hope it helps.